# TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'datetime.datetime' when running python manage.py migrate

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models

I am taking a course on Udemy and I came across this error when running

```
python manage.py migrate
```

The error is:

```
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'datetime.datetime'
```

Here is my code:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.


class Tweet(models.Model):
    # user
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    content = models.CharField(max_length=140)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.content)
```

My traceback:

```
File "manage.py", line 15, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Users/isaac/Dev/tweetme/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 371, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Users/isaac/Dev/tweetme/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 365, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/Users/isaac/Dev/tweetme/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 288, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/Users/isaac/Dev/tweetme/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 335, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/Users/isaac/Dev/tweetme/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 200, in handle
    fake_initial=fake_initial,
  File "/Users/isaac/Dev/tweetme/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 117, in migrate
    state = self._migrate_all_forwards(state, plan, full_plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/Users/isaac/Dev/tweetme/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 147, in _migrate_all_forwards
    state = self.apply_migration(state, migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/Users/isaac/Dev/tweetme/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 244, in apply_migration
    state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)
  File "/Users/isaac/Dev/tweetme/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/migration.py", line 122, in apply
    operation.database_forwards(self.app_label, schema_editor, old_state, project_state)
  File "/Users/isaac/Dev/tweetme/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/operations/fields.py", line 84, in database_forwards
    field,
  File "/Users/isaac/Dev/tweetme/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/schema.py", line 306, in add_field
    self._remake_table(model, create_field=field)
  File "/Users/isaac/Dev/tweetme/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/schema.py", line 178, in _remake_table
    self.effective_default(create_field)
  File "/Users/isaac/Dev/tweetme/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 240, in effective_default
    default = field.get_db_prep_save(default, self.connection)
  File "/Users/isaac/Dev/tweetme/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related.py", line 936, in get_db_prep_save
    return self.target_field.get_db_prep_save(value, connection=connection)
  File "/Users/isaac/Dev/tweetme/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 767, in get_db_prep_save
    return self.get_db_prep_value(value, connection=connection, prepared=False)
  File "/Users/isaac/Dev/tweetme/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 939, in get_db_prep_value
    value = self.get_prep_value(value)
  File "/Users/isaac/Dev/tweetme/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 947, in get_prep_value
    return int(value)
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'datetime.datetime'
```

This error was created as soon as I added the `users`.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: add your traceback also

Comment: Done. added traceback

Comment: The error is raising because the program trying to convert a value ( a `datetime` object) to a `int` type. Unfortunately it's not possible in `Python`

Comment: From the given model, it seems like fine. Anyway try to flush/delete all the data from DB and try again